# How to resolve iisconfigurator .exe has stopped working?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I using visual studio 2012,i have a problem when i debug my project it shows this error.How can i resolve this .[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Try to install the IIS Management Console.

I found this post: http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2012/07/iisconfiguratorexe.html, but I didn't need to install "Internet Infromation Services Hostable Web Core", only the management console.

I'm running w8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtkjD.png